# Im trying to slice a prompt into its individual letters and have them correlate to images

Tags: javascript

I have very basic knowledge of javascript so I have don't know where to go with this. Im trying to take a users phrase and then display it with favicons. This is run through a bookmark i.g. "javascript: code" put in the url box of a bookmark. I don't know why they want more details, I don't really have more detail to add. I know it would help but I don't really know where to start.

Current code:

```
var phrase = localStorage.getItem("phrase");
if (!phrase) {
phrase = prompt("Please enter phrase");
localStorage.setItem("phrase", phrase);
}



const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const loop = async () => {
for (let i = 1;
    let i > 0; i++) {

    var text = localStorage.getItem("phrase");
    var letter1 = text.charAt(0);
    var letter2 = text.charAt(1);
    var letter3 = text.charAt(2);
    var letter4 = text.charAt(3);
    var letter5 = text.charAt(4);
    var letter6 = text.charAt(5);
    var letter7 = text.charAt(6);
    var letter8 = text.charAt(7);
    var letter9 = text.charAt(8);
    var letter10 = text.charAt(9);
    var letter11 = text.charAt(10);
    var letter12 = text.charAt(11);
    var letter13 = text.charAt(12);
    var letter14 = text.charAt(13);
    var letter15 = text.charAt(14);
    var letter16 = text.charAt(15);
    var letter17 = text.charAt(16);
    var letter18 = text.charAt(17);
    var letter19 = text.charAt(18);
    var letter20 = text.charAt(19);
    var letter21 = text.charAt(20);
    var letter22 = text.charAt(21);
    var letter23 = text.charAt(22);
    var letter24 = text.charAt(23);
    var letter25 = text.charAt(24);
    var letter26 = text.charAt(25);
    var letter27 = text.charAt(26);

    var a = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-27/faa8394cf7c568bb6e01abd81ca75367.ico";
    var b = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-31/301ad3d8d299265516f218d0ad17a3cb.ico";
    var c = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-29/ffad968f613d041521ba8adde62617e0.ico";
    var d = "https://awscdn.detik.net.id/detikcom/images/favicon.ico?v=202206181563";
    var e = "https://a.espncdn.com/favicon.ico";
    var f = "https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yD/r/d4ZIVX-5C-b.ico";
    var g = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-30/c1570e180fba5f7d040578a55716d3e5.ico";
    var h = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-30/a9be1eeb27707db5ed07cfcc6cffa26d.ico";
    var i = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-29/c1e50d5e53bdb89ce8a5ddd7500e0429.ico";
    var j = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-31/77088bfaaf3aabf89c1af83880815b35.ico";
    var k = "https://cdn1.kongcdn.com/compiled-assets/favicos/favico-32-2138c9508a9befc2a8c124bd8b8ce07e6a81d6193b113faea844f47afba467f3.png";
    var l = "https://www.parallels.com/typo3conf/ext/prls_theme/Resources/Public/theme/res/img/favicon/favicon.png";
    var m = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-30/6884cede50ac13526932d551e615ecc9.ico";
    var n = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-20/25485f3390ae95f80a18b6d43a7cd731.ico";
    var o = "https://cdn-production-opera-website.operacdn.com/staticfiles/assets/images/favicon/favicon.12c955371a4b.ico";
    var p = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-25/d8a9aaf4710e20838af3899073deb727.ico";
    var q = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-31/226cfd2f7570859c53d5e10ac6dd152d.ico";
    var r = "https://www.rakuten.co.jp/favicon.ico";
    var s = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-02-02/8b57e489692b1704c56585a1a017f9d1.ico";
    var t = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-30/15d3afa8f2a8e800cd20bb17845ca56f.ico";
    var u = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-01-22/380cdc8045136b58dea2a4df83142c8f.ico";
    var v = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-02-03/81cfc3ee4c7e23f559004ea4b5515ee3.ico";
    var w = "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico";
    var x = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2014-12-14/10407010e66df693581c53c6a03bc4fa.ico";
    var y = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2015-02-02/042180ff74ed65b9baae3da9a0c8f809.ico";
    var z = "https://favicon-generator.org/favicon-generator/htdocs/favicons/2014-12-28/9f04865d5cc9f9e577e344ef73030f3a.ico";

    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/png';
    link.href = letter1;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter2;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter3;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter4;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter5;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter6;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter7;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter8;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter9;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter10;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter11;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter12;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter13;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter14;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter15;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter16;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter17;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter18;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter19;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter20;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter21;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter22;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter23;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter24;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter25;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter26;
    await wait(1000)
    link.href = letter27;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    await wait(1500)
}
}
loop()
```

Comment: You'll want to learn about arrays and loops

Comment: "*I don't know why they want more details, I don't really have more detail to add*" - well you could ask a question or describe the problem you have with this code. What help do you want?